# How to identify the reason for a HTTP 403?

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I am writing a python module that requires downloading a corpus of data from a variety of sources.

One of my sources is now throwing an HTTP403 error. I cannot figure out why. I have tried copying the entire GET request from Chrome's network tab, and I still get a HTTP 403 from the request module. Any ideas?

```
import requests

source = 'https://www.cell.com/cms/10.1016/j.cell.2018.03.074/attachment/2a72a316-33cc-427d-8019-dfc83bd220ca/mmc4.zip'
request_headers = {
   "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "macOS",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",

}
# raises http 403
with requests.get(source,headers=request_headers, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: You're getting hit by Cloudflare anti-bot measures, try using selenium with undetected-chromedriver?